# pdfgrep: searching for sequence with space in between (on mac)

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I need a pdfgrep query to get string with space in between. Like between the characters "r" and "fr".

i.e it should return strings like:

```
'r fresh', 'r fry', 'r france'
```

I tried:

```
pdfgrep -r r fr  > rfr.txt
```

Comment: if it's like other grep utilities you want `pdfgrep -r 'r fr'`

Comment: ps - since this isn't a programming question, it's off-topic.  You might have been better off on unix.stackexchange or superuser.

Comment: Can you put the sample text for which you are running the query, as this might make the question more clear.

Comment: thank you @zzxyz! your code works. sorry that I posted it in the wrong group :(